# Prevent Angular 6 router from overriding routes defined in Express Server

Tags: node.js, angular, express, webpack, angular2-routing

How do I prevent Angular routing from interferring with routes from an Express Node Server?

I'm setting up some routes ( to node-RED middleware) in my Express server:

server.js

```
    // Serve the editor UI from /red
app.use(settings.httpAdminRoot,RED.httpAdmin);

// Serve the http nodes UI from /api
app.use(settings.httpNodeRoot,RED.httpNode);

// Angular DIST output folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Send all other requests to the Angular app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.js'));
});
```

but in my router module they get always overridden ( with our without the default path redirection)

routing.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "example-page",
        loadChildren: "../modules/example/example.module#ExampleModule?sync=true"
    },
    // Last routing path specifies default path for application entry
/*    {
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: "/example-page",
        pathMatch: "full"
    },*/
];
```

I'm only providing this little code because I want to ask in general **how do I prevent Angular from interferring with routes defined in an Express server** and what is the best practice for routing in an Express/ Node.js + Angular + AspNetCore + Webpack app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Angular, then let Angular handle all pages. This code takes care of that and hence angular is handling all routes.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.js'));
});
```

If you want express to handle some routes instead of angular, handle that route before handling angular route as follows:

```
app.get('/some-non-angular-path', (req, res) => {
   //code to handle this path. once it is handled here, angular won't be involved
   //non-angular-paths should come first in the order
});
app.get((req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.js'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I thought so too, hence I put the the "app.use(settings.httpAdminRoot,RED.httpAdmin)" part before the angular route handling part. But maybe app.use wont work here for some reason. I'll give it a try and then accept your answer ;)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. unfortunatley no! your answer makes sense though and might help others so if nobody else has any idea ill accept it to let it help others

Comment: By the way, if you trying to route to `some-non-angular-path` in angular routing itself, then it won't work. You have to redirect by giving full path for example say `window.location.href='http://localhost:3000/some-non-angular-path'` on click of the link/button. This way, it'll reach app.js in server side and the corresponding route will be handled and not angular. This worked when I tried.